# How to write code simply using stream api

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following classes:

```
@Getter
public class SomeClass implements Serializable {
    private LocalDate date;
    private String smth;
    List<PairKeyValue> quotaParams;
}
```

The class PairKeyValue is just:

```
@Getter
public class PairKeyValue implements Serializable {

    private String key;
    private String value;
}
```

I want to do the following:

1) Check if in `SomeClass's` date equals sysdate then check value under `key="somekey"` in `list<PairKeyValue>` is equals to 1 (`somekey = 1`) then left it in list.

2) Check if in `SomeClass's` `date` NOT equals `sysdate` then check value under `key="somekey"` in `List<PairKeyValue>` is equals to 0 (`somekey = 0`) then left it in list.

3) And ignore other values.

So in the end I need a filtered list of only current values within `SomeClass`.

I have my realization but I don't like it is not using only stream API:

availableQuotes = ArrayList();

```
 if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(availableQuotes)) {
        availableQuotes = availableQuotes
                .stream()
                .filter(this::checkDate).collect(toList());
    }

    private boolean checkDate (SomeClass someClass){
        if (someClass.getDate().equals(LocalDate.now())) {
            return checkDuration(someClass, "0");
        } else {
            return checkDuration(someClass, "1");
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDuration (SomeClass someClass, String param){
        List<PairKeyValue> quotaParams = someClass.getPairKeyValues().stream()
                .filter(spKeyValue -> spKeyValue.getKey().equals("duration"))
                .filter(spKeyValue -> spKeyValue.getValue().equals(param))
                .collect(toList());
        return (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(quotaParams));
    }
```

I know it looks awful and I know it can be more readable so please help.

Comment: So you want to rewrite all your functions so it is included in a single stream filter ?

Comment: what is availableQuotes? I think a more complete code will be beneficial :) What does SPQuota class contain?

Comment: @PaulLemarchand how can you see i used 2 private methods but i know there is an another implementation without any supporting methods

Comment: @triForce420 availableQuotes just a List<SomeClass>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question right, the last 2 functions can be resumed to the following:

```
availableQuotes = availableQuotes.stream()
            .filter(availableQuote -> availableQuote.getQuotaParams().stream()
                    .anyMatch(quotaParam -> quotaParam.getKey().equals("duration")
                            && quotaParam.getValue().equals(availableQuote.getDate().equals(LocalDate.now()) ? "0" : "1")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I mostly took your code and re-arranged it into a single filter.